# Simplification of exponential formula

Tags: exponential-function

Consider,
$$\frac{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}$$
Can this be reduced to
$$\frac{e^{i\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}+1}$$
If so how? What identity to use?

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{i\theta/2}$. Note the first form tells you this ratio is $i\tan(\theta/2)$ which is nice

Comment: Converting the denominator of the second formula to a real number gives you a nice expression in terms of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$.